# NoMethodError: undefined method `user=' rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using this factory file for `user` model:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do |f|
    f.sequence(:first_name) { |n| "#{Faker::Name.first_name}foo#{n}" }
    f.sequence(:last_name) { |n| "#{Faker::Name.last_name}foo#{n}" }
    f.sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    f.password "foobar"
    f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
    f.sequence(:confirmed_at) { Date.today }
    f.sequence(:telephone_number) { Faker::Number.number(10) }
    f.sequence(:mobile_phone_number) { Faker::Number.number(10) }
    f.sequence(:verification_code) { '0000' }
    f.sequence(:is_verified) { false }
  end
end
```

and `Order.rb` factory is:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :order do
    association :store
    association :user
    total_price Faker::Number.positive
    total_discount Faker::Number.positive
  end
end
```

And the `order` model should have these three FKs, two of which are from `User`:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :carrier, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :store
end
```

and in `order_controllers_spec.rb` file, I got these:

```
let(:customer) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
let(:carrier) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
let(:store) { FactoryBot.create(:store) }
let(:order) { FactoryBot.create(:order, customer_id: customer.id, carrier_id: carrier.id, store_id: store.id) }
```

Each time I run the `show` test,

```
describe "GET show" do
    it 'has a 200 status code' do
        get :show, params: { id: order_item.id }
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
end
```

I got this error

```
Failure/Error: let(:order) { FactoryBot.create(:order, customer_id: customer.id, carrier_id: carrier.id, store_id: store.id) }

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `user=' for #<Order:0x00007fcd2efc5118>
```

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: You `belongs_to` associations with `:customer` and `:carrier` are ambiguous.

Comment: Show some stack trace if available.

Comment: The error comes from `FactoryBot.create(:order ...)`. Where's your **orders** factory? That's the source of the problem, not user users factory.

Comment: @TomLord Just updated the question with factory file for Order!

Comment: @MohammadEliassAlhusain `association :user` -- and there's the problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in your `Order`'s factory definition you're using `user`, instead of `customer` or `carrier` as your `Order` model define.

```
association :customer, factory: :user
association :carrier,  factory: :user
```

Comment: Just updated the question with factory file for Order!

Comment: Nailed it, AMAZING!
Thanks, I've been stuck here from yesterday!!!!!! :(

Comment: You know you should ask to us :D